# How can I create map with nil value in one field and then marshal it to json?

Tags: go

I need get json string

```
{"Error": null }
```

I can do this using this approach

```golang
type OKResponse struct {
    Error *int `json:"Error"`
}

encoded, err := json.Marshal(OKResponse{})
...
```

How I can get the same result using map? Or it is not possible?

For example something like this

```golang
jsonbody := map[string]int{"Error": nil}
encoded, err := json.Marshal(&jsonbody)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular case you may use:

```
jsonbody := map[string]error{"Error": nil}
```

But for more generalized you may also use:

```
jsonbody := map[string]interface{}{"Error": nil}
```

Both approaches will produce:

```
{"Error":null}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since number can't get a `nil` value you can't do that.

What you can do is to use a pointer type and then it can be done, something like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    jsonbody := map[string]*int{"Error": nil}
    encoded, _ := json.Marshal(&jsonbody)
    fmt.Printf("%s", encoded)

    num := 6
    jsonbody = map[string]*int{"Error": &num}
    encoded, _ = json.Marshal(&jsonbody)
    fmt.Printf("%s", encoded)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/TTpgr7Cy17C

Comment: What if map will use other type for filed?

Comment: You can have an empty interface as the value for map, something like: `map[string]interface{}{"Error": 5, "Success": nil}` but that would mean any value can be assigned to the map as value.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the type to `*int`, it will do what you want:

```
type OKResponse struct {
    Error *int `json:"Error"`
}
```

Example:

```
r1 := OKResponse{}
result1, _ := json.Marshal(r1)
fmt.Printf("result1 = %s\n", string(result1))

errNo := 1
r2 := OKResponse{Error: &errNo}
result2, _ := json.Marshal(r2)
fmt.Printf("result2 = %s\n", string(result2))
```

Output:

```
result1 = {"Error":null}
result2 = {"Error":1}
```

See it [in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6RiRAF_VkVD).